# How to extract duplicate keys and values from a list of python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dicts that are taken from a product and its variants, which is defined like so:

```
attribute_list = [
    {'Finish': 'Chrome'},
    {'Size': 'Large'},
    {'Weight': '1.6kg'},
    {'Finish': 'Chrome'},
    {'Weight': '1.9kg'}
]
```

I am looking to create two lists, one that has dicts that are not duplicated in the list i.e:

```
compiled_list = [
    {'Finish': 'Chrome'}
    {'Size': 'Large'}
]
```

...and another which has the duplicated keys and values in it, i.e:

```
duplicates_list = [
    {'Weight': '1.6kg'}
    {'Weight': '1.9kg'}
]
```

Below is the code that I have so far, this gets me as far as having two dictionaries but 1) I think this is horribly inefficent and 2) I can't work out how to remove the first instance of a duplicate dictionary.

```
compiled_list = list()
compiled_list_keys = list()
duplicates_list = list()
for attribute in attribute_list:
    for k, v in attribute.items():
        if k not in compiled_list_keys:
            compiled_list_keys.append(k)
            compiled_list.append(attribute)
        else:
            if attribute not in compiled_list:
                duplicates_list.append(attribute)
                compiled_list_keys.remove(k)
```

Comment: Are those things that you show lists or dicts? The syntax is a mix of two, and the text says "list of dict".

Comment: each of them is probably an individual dict.

Comment: Yes, they are individual dicts apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @PeteDermott Why is `{'Finish': 'Chrome'}` in the compiled_list which aren't duplicated?

Comment: @PeteDermott Can each individual dict have more than one key/value pair ? If so, what is the expected result ?

Comment: @KévinBarré, no, the dict will always be on key/value pair

Comment: @ZainPatel, the dicts are formed from a product and its variants, because both instances of Finish have the same value, they can be combined into a single entry in the compiled_list

Comment: Question: is it OK to change the data type? It seems to me like a poor choice of list + dict.

Comment: @ibarrond: Sure, if needs be

Comment: @PeteDermott Then I propose my solution using Pandas! (check below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution involves using **Pandas**, a Python package much more suited for data management. You will see why:

1. First we convert the list of dicts to pandas. Here we drop exact duplicates:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame([list(attr.items())[0] for attr in attribute_list],
                     columns=['key', 'value']).drop_duplicates()
   #>      key     value
     0     Finish  Chrome
     1     Size    Large
     2     Weight  1.6kg
     4     Weight  1.9kg
   ```
2. Now we apply our search functions. This is VERY EASY using pandas:

   ```
   compiled_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='key', keep=False)
   #>      key     value
     0     Finish  Chrome
     1     Size    Large
   duplicated_df=df[df.key.duplicated(keep=False)]
   #>      key     value
     2     Weight  1.6kg
     4     Weight  1.9kg
   ```
3. Now we convert back to the original list of dicts:

   ```
   compiled_list = [{item.key: item.value} for item in compiled_df.itertuples()]
   #> [{'Finish': 'Chrome'}, {'Size': 'Large'}]

   duplicated_list = [{item.key: item.value} for item in duplicated_df.itertuples()]
   #> [{'Weight': '1.6kg'}, {'Weight': '1.9kg'}
   ```

It might not be the most efficient way, but it is by far much more versatile. In short, 5 lines of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(attr.items())[0] for attr in attribute_list],
                      columns=['key', 'value']).drop_duplicates()
compiled_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='key', keep=False)
duplicated_df=df[df.key.duplicated(keep=False)]
compiled_list = [{item.key: item.value} for item in compiled_df.itertuples()]
duplicated_list = [{item.key: item.value} for item in duplicated_df.itertuples()]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you append `attribute` to `duplicate_list`, you have to check for any other exiting attribute in `compiled_list` with similar key and remove it from `compiled_list` and append it to `duplicate_list`

```
compiled_list = list()
compiled_list_keys = list()
duplicates_list = list()
for attribute in attribute_list:
    for k, v in attribute.items():
        if k not in compiled_list_keys:
            compiled_list_keys.append(k)
            compiled_list.append(attribute)
        else:
            if attribute not in compiled_list:
                exiting_attribute = [d for d in compiled_list if k in d][0]
                compiled_list.remove(exiting_attribute)
                duplicates_list.append(exiting_attribute)
                duplicates_list.append(attribute)
                compiled_list_keys.remove(k)
print (compiled_list)
print (duplicates_list)
```

**Output**

```
[{'Finish': 'Chrome'}, {'Size': 'Large'}]
[{'Weight': '1.6kg'}, {'Weight': '1.9kg'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can restructure your list of dictionaries as a `defaultdict` of `set` objects.

Then use a couple of list comprehensions to separate isolated items from duplicates:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

for item in attribute_list:
    key, value = next(iter(item.items()))
    d[key].add(value)

compiled_list = [{k: next(iter(v))} for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == 1]
duplicates_list = [{k: w} for k, v in d.items() for w in v if len(v) > 1]

print(compiled_list, duplicates_list, sep='\n')

[{'Finish': 'Chrome'}, {'Size': 'Large'}]
[{'Weight': '1.6kg'}, {'Weight': '1.9kg'}]
```